# TiddlyWiki Table of Contents sorting

Tags: sorting, wiki, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I am looking to make a table of contents that may contain a structure as follows:

- Topic 1

  - **Overview**
  - Content A
  - Content B
  - Content C
- Topic 2

  - **Overview**
  - Content D
  - Content E
  - Content F

1)  I would like to **manually** sort these in a specific order, and by this I mean not alphabetical order (ex: sort[title])

2) If possible, I would like to be able to contain more than one **Overview** tiddler but have them be unique to the **Topic** in which they're contained.

***Im trying to avoid having to do redundant titles like:***

- Topic 1

  - **Overview - Topic 1**
  - Content A
  - Content B
  - Content C

Answer (score 1):

Got a partial answer for the manual sorting.

**Topic 1**

- Add a "new field" called "content-index" = 0

**Topic 2**

- Add a "new field" callled "content-index" = 1

etc.

Under the table of contents tiddler:

```
<div class="tc-table-of-contents">
<<toc-selective-expandable 'Contents' sort[content-index]>>
</div>
```

Still researching to find out if I can, at the very least, **visually** show non-unique entries in the content tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do sorting by including the sub-topics in the "list" field of the main tiddler in the correct order, each one surrounded by brackets. I also like your solution with "content-index" though.

About redundant titles, you can use a lengthier title to ensure that it's unique, and then set the "caption" field to something shorter, e.g. "Overview". Then the table of contents automatically shows the caption, but internally the tiddler is known by its real title.